# How to join all elements in object js

Tags: javascript

I have object

```
PhoneConfirmationFormValues = {
  num1: string;
  num2: string;
  num3: string;
  num4: string;
};
```

I need the get all values like `PhoneConfirmationFormValues` = 1234.

Comment: Please take five minutes to properly explain your problem, the input and the expected output. `:string` is not valid Javascript, this language is not typed. Also where does the `1234` come from? You also need to provide what you've tried so far, and explain where exactly you are stuck. You can't just come here and dump "I want this."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get all the values as a string it should be just a matter of doing this

```js
const PhoneConfirmationFormValues = {
  num1: 1,
  num2: 2,
  num3: 3,
  num4: 4,
};

const result = Object.values(PhoneConfirmationFormValues).join("")

console.log(result)
```

Object.values, return all the values from all the keys in your object as an array, and with that you can use the Array.join method to transform your array items in and string which in this case the separator is a blank string.

If you want the result as a number you can do

```
Number(result)
```